Why am I having issues with RAM overclocking on an MSI B550 Tomahawk AMD motherboard?
I installed new RAM into my computer a few weeks ago (2 x 16 DDR4 3600Mhz)  and I had to go into my BIOS and manually change the speeds from 2133 to 3600. I have an MSI B550 Tomahawk AMD motherboard.
I switched it over and my computer started to repeatedly crash until I allocated the ram more power. Some Reddit user suggested to change it from 1.192V to 1.35V and that fixed the problem almost fully.
However while trying to play OG Fortnite today I crashed both times. But I've been able to play other games without a problem in the 2 weeks that it's been in.

2133 to 3600 that’s a very significant overclock. If you reduce that down to say 3000 is the overclock stable? That’s a 60% overclock. You would need insane cooling on the processor to make that system stable.
